# Exit code of a sourced shell script

Tags: bash, return, exit-code

Shell scripts can be sourced, i.e. executed in the current shell, like

```
. ~/some_script.sh
```

but they can also be invoked via a subshell, e.g.

```
/bin/bash ~/another_script.sh
```

Writing one script I was changing its scheme from sourcing to subshell and then back to sourcing. There are things that make writing different. And now I’m stuck with exit statuses, cause I’m not sure — do `return` statuses interfere with those ones the `exit` produces? Cause on [tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) is written some statuses are reserved, but all the examples are about the `exit` directive. So do these restrictions related to return codes too?

All the useful I found in ABS guide is *‘A `return` command optionally takes an integer argument, which is returned to the calling script as the "exit status" of the function, and this exit status is assigned to the variable $?.’*, but I’m in doubt about *‘as’*, and quotes around ‘exit status’.

Answer (score 0):

The codes returned from `return` and `exit` are identical, the keywords are just used in different contexts (`return` for returning from functions and sourcings, `exit` for exiting the current shell).

They don't interfere with each other as such, but an `exit` or `return` without an argument will use the return value of the previous command, which may have been specified in another `exit` or `return` statement.

Comment: What kind of example do you need?

Comment: There is link to tldp.org in the first post.